# How to display Break page by default with XLSXWRITER

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I added the configuration of break page .I want to know if is it possible to display page break view by default in xlsxwriter (python)?

I tried with `sheet.set_page_break_view()` but I got error .

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
Given that Xlsxwriter 3.1.2 has been released on May 29th 2023 it would no longer be necessary to make code modification to enable `pageBreakPreview` per [@jmcnamara answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76352033/13664137) in this post.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

There has been some talk of adding this in but looking at the 'xlswriter worksheet code' in version 3.1.1 `worksheet.set_page_view()` still only allows for enabling one option

```
def set_page_view(self):
    """
    Set the page view mode.
    Args:
        None.
    Returns:
        Nothing.
    """
    self.page_view = 1
```

and that one option is `pageLayout`

```
# Set the page view/layout mode if required.
if self.page_view:
    attributes.append(("view", "pageLayout"))
```

If you are happy to edit the xlsxwriter worksheet file you can easily change that one option to

```
if self.page_view:
    attributes.append(("view", "pageBreakPreview"))
```

so that using

```
worksheet.set_page_view()
```

will then set the view to `pageBreakPreview` rather than `pageLayout` view.

Or you can edit so either (or all three including 'normal') can be selected.

I'm sure that @jmcnamara will provide any updated details if I've missed something.

Comment: It was an oversight not to include a Page Break view mode originally in XlsxWriter. I recently added it to the Rust version of the library but forgot to back (forward?) port it to the Python version. I'll look into fixing that.

Answer (score 2):

I've added this as a feature to XlsxWriter v3.1.2 via the `worksheet.set_pagebreak_view()` method:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write("A1", "Hello")
worksheet.write("Z100", "Hello")

worksheet.set_h_pagebreaks([10, 20, 30, 40])

worksheet.set_pagebreak_view()

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]